# How to handle device time and Amazon S3 time conflicts gracefully?

Tags: ios, amazon-s3

Amazon S3, at times sends a 403 while writing to the bucket, when the difference between current time there and request time exceeds by more than around 5 minutes.

So if the time on device time is not proper, it gives problem with S3 uploads.

So how should one gracefully handle such case ?

Should I ask the server for its time and then decide if device time is fine or not ?
should the user be given an alert if the time is way different form server's time ?